# Too many vlc activeX controls on form crashes app

Tags: c#, winforms, vlc

I have a video monitoring app using VS2012 in C# using the vlc activex plugin.  I can embed and watch around 30 videos with no issues.  Once I get around 35, I get random crashes.  At 40, the crashes are immediate.  The crashes usually don't give me any info, but sometimes I get an nvidia video driver crashed message.  Another error that sometimes pops up is a GDI 'Parameter is Not Valid'  error.  To rule out any problems with my code, I got rid of all control items except vlc and the problem still occurs.

If I run two instances on the app, each with 20 video windows, I have no issues.

Is this some limit I am hitting because of the single thread?  Any workaround ideas?

Comment: This kind of code tends to fall down pretty badly when Windows applies the handle quota to processes.  Programmers tend to skip the required error handling, tough to deal with a low-level winapi function failing.  It all comes tumbling down when the code starts passing garbage values to functions, trigger null pointer crashes and "parameter not valid" errors.  Somebody ought to submit a patch but nobody has time for it because it doesn't actually fix the core problem: using too many resources.

Answer (score 0):

you need more server and memory space to get more than 25 videos in single screen, your local machine with i7 processor does not help you to resolve this issue. i know VLC is best video development kit, and this is the only kit that can give you more video than others in single screen with low memory and CPU utilization.

Best wishes to get resolve this issue ASP, and post the article if you resolve this issue

Comment: But why can I get 40 videos to play by running two instances of app on same machine,  but not get 40 videos to play in a single instance?  I've got an 8-core machine and its only hitting around 30% CPU Utilization with 30 videos playing.

Comment: Use VMMap to check memory usage of your process... sounds like you're running out of memory and running into OutOfMemory Exceptions...

Comment: @GerbilWockey If VLC is not a 64-bit application then you could be running into memory limitations on a single process that you would not encounter by using two.

Comment: Also, perfmon can be used to check the memory usage of your app, you should view both native and managed memory resources.

Comment: Just to update... I tried putting each row of videos on its own form and setting each form in a new thread.  That didn't fix the issue either.  The vlc activex plugin is 32bit only, so I couldn't try building for 64bit.